# Angular Tour of Heroes - Testing project included but not working

Tags: angular, angular5, angular-cli, angular-tour-of-heroes

I downloaded the Angular Tour of Heroes testing project [here](https://angular.io/guide/testing). I am getting the following errors right from the start. Any ideas?

> ERROR in Entry module not found: Error: Can't resolve
>   'C:\code\testing\src\test.ts' in 'C:\code\testing'
>
> ERROR in error TS6053: File 'C:/code/testing/src/test.ts' not found.
>   src/app/twain/twain.component.marbles.spec.ts(3,40): error TS2307:
>   Cannot find module 'jasmine-marbles'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get it working in a few steps.

1. Open the `angular.json` file.

   > test => options => main
   >
   > Change `"main": "src/test.ts",` to `"main": "src/tests.sb.ts",`
2. Open the `tsconfig.spec.json` file.

   > Change this:
   >       "files": [
   >       "test.ts",
   >       "polyfills.ts"
   >       ],
   >       To this:
   >       "files": [
   >       "tests.sb.ts",
   >       "polyfills.ts"
   >       ],
3. Run this:

   ```
   npm i jasmine-marbles
   ```
4. Then run your test.

   ```
   npm test
   ```

Your tests should now be working.

Comment: I don't get any errors anymore, however, none of the tests gets executed?